# can I build a production level windows application in Python

Tags: python, c++, windows, installation

I'm trying to build a Windows Application in Python.
But, sometimes I question myself, can this Application run on another person's PC without installing Python?
Will it have any flows because of python?
I heard most people use C++ for Windows Applications?
Will I be able to provide Updates for my Application to every user by Python code?

Comment: Google pyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can Definitely Create a Production Level App Using Python
And the App can be run-able on any other person's Computer Without Installing python

Also, many Big companies use python to build desktop Apps
You can start making desktop apps using these python Frameworks -

- Tkinter
- Kivy
- PysimpleGUI
- PyQt

Answer (score 0):

By generating an executable of your application it will run on someone else's PC without installing Python.
PyInstaller performs this task of generating the executable.
The flow is to generate the app executable by packaging python inside the app.
You will be able to update the application indirectly by updating accessory files. In case the python code has changed, you will have to generate a new executable.